# Getting Model from Filter after RedirectToAction

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Currently have an Action Filter which basically checks the TempData and if there is items in the TempData of a certain type it adds it to the Model. This works perfectly when browsing the site which are all 'Return View(model)' etc. However at one point I want to perform a 'RedirectToAction' which does not work. The model is always NULL.

The Filter...

```
public class ToastFilter : IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        var _tempDataDictionaryFactory = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(ITempDataDictionaryFactory)) as ITempDataDictionaryFactory;

        var result = context.Result as ViewResult;
        var tempData = _tempDataDictionaryFactory.GetTempData(context.HttpContext);

        var model = result?.Model as MyApp.Common.Models.Misc.BaseModel;

        if (model == null)
            return;

        if (tempData.Keys.Count > 0)
            model.Toasts.AddRange(tempData.Where(td => td.Value is ToastModel).Select(td => td.Value as ToastModel));
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        //Do Nothing
    }
}
```

The Controller...

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [AuthorizeRoles(Settings.SystemAdministratorRole, "Company_Admin")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(CompanyDetailsModel model)
    {
        var modelText = _stringLocalizerFactory.Create(typeof(CompanyDetailsModel));
        var commonText = _stringLocalizerFactory.Create(typeof(Common.System.Resource.CommonResources));

        if (!ValidationManager.IsValid(ModelState, model.DynamicProperties))
        {
            TempData.Add(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), ValidationManager.CreateValidationMessage(ModelState, model));

            return View(model);
        }

        var companyExists = model.CompanyId.HasValue;
        var companyUpsertResult = await _company.UpsertCompany(model);

        switch (companyUpsertResult.Item1)
        {
            case GenericOutcome.Success:
                TempData.Add(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                             companyExists
                                 ? ToastHelper.GenerateToast(modelText["UpdateSuccessMessage"],
                                                             commonText["Success"], Icons.ThumbsUp, 5000,
                                                             ToastSize.Small, Settings.GreenMessage)
                                 : ToastHelper.GenerateToast(modelText["CreateSuccessMessage"],
                                                             commonText["Success"], Icons.ThumbsUp, 5000,
                                                             ToastSize.Small, Settings.GreenMessage));
                return RedirectToAction("List");
            case GenericOutcome.Failure:
                TempData.Add(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                             companyExists
                                 ? ToastHelper.GenerateToast(modelText["UpdateFailedMessage"],
                                                             commonText["Failure"], Icons.ThumbsDown,
                                                             5000, ToastSize.Small, Settings.RedMessage)
                                 : ToastHelper.GenerateToast(modelText["CreateFailedMessage"],
                                                             commonText["Failure"], Icons.ThumbsDown,
                                                             5000, ToastSize.Small, Settings.RedMessage));
                return View(model);
        }

        return View(model);
    }

    [Authorize(Roles = Settings.SystemAdministratorRole)]
    public IActionResult List()
    {
        var model = new CompanyListModel();

        return View(model);
    }
```

This is where it fails to recognise that it has a model. It all works perfectly if the the Generic Outcome is a fail and it uses the standard Return View(model) route.

Any idea how to get the filter to work if it used via a 'RedirectToAction'?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that `CompanyListModel` inherits `MyApp.Common.Models.Misc.BaseModel`?

Comment: Yup.... `public class CompanyListModel : BaseModel { }`

Comment: What is `context.ActionDescriptor.DisplayName` in your filter, when Model is null?